# Usage of charset in the script tag for Javascript

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I need to include text of different languages in the javascript app that I'm writing, and the characters need to show up properly in different webpages that have different page encodings.  The script is external.

I've read that in order to have the browser correctly interpret and display these characters, a charset tag should be added in the script tag.  However, I am facing a few problems with this approach and would like to see if anyone could help.

1. The order of the charset seems to matter in IE9.  Should "charset" be declared before "src" in the script tag?  Is there such a specification or did anyone see a similar issue?
2. I've seen someone comment in another forum that the charset in an element will not be processed if the webpage defines a charset in the http content type/meta (or something along that line).  Is this true?  Does this mean that the charset in the script tag will be ignored then?  If so, how to overcom
3. Are there any other recommended methods besides using charset in the script tag?  Manipulating the webpages is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you have multiple js files each one using a different encoding, and you tried the charset on the `<script>` tag but that is causing you troubles.

If so, have you tried not adding the charset at all and having the javascript files encoded in Unicode? I found that to be the best in having the browser actually render the correct fonts.

[read this for some examples](http://www.capitolacomputing.com/intl_js_charset.htm) and let us know if it works out for you!

Comment: Thanks for the link! I've actually already read this before posting, and the author placed the charset attribute before the scr attribute, so it works on IE 9.  I actually only have 1 js file which needs to be use on multiple webpages that have different encodings.  Not adding charset will result in garbled characters in one of the browsers (I can't recall if it's chrome or mozilla or IE anymore after all these experiments), and I think there will be problems when the webpage is encoded in a different encoding as the js file.  I am speaking in the context of using UTF-8 without signature.

Comment: what I got from the link above is that there's no reason to add that charset attribute at all (nor use a UTF-8 signature). All it's saying is that you can encode in JS the special characters as Unicode (using that \uXXX format), and the browser can then show them correctly no matter which charset is used...

Comment: I have many strings to display, so it might be an issue to manage them in the \uXXX format.  But I will keep this option in mind.

Comment: the article talks about a tool that can do that for you - I can see a pre-build script in your make file that could automate all of this... Of course it's all a bit hackery, I agree, but then that's what we web developers do all the time, right? ;-)

Comment: The link in this answer is dead. the domain `capitolacomputing.com` is apparently defunct.